# Scroll down html table using selenium and python

Tags: html, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scroll down an HTML table until the last row is visible, the table initially loads about 20 rows and then loads more as I scroll down. I am using selenium webdriver and python to automate this process but so far i am stuck as my code below is scrolling down the whole page instead of this particular table which is passed as an argument in the function.

here is my code
the web element to be scrolled is passed as an argument as well as the number of times it will be scrolled down

```
def scroll_down_element(self, element, times):
    try:
        action_chain = ActionChains(self.browser)
        counter = 0
        while(counter < times):
            element.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
            counter += 1
            sleep(0.25)
    except Exception as e:
        print 'error scrolling down web element', e
```

All suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the code that I resorted to after trying a few different combinations of javascript and other selenium methods. Space scrolls down deeper than ARROW_DOWN or the DOWN Key.

```
def scroll_down_element(self, element, times):
    try:
        action = ActionChains(self.browser)
        action.move_to_element(element).perform()
        element.click() 
        for _ in range(times):
            element.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
            sleep(0.1)
    except Exception as e:
        print 'error scrolling down web element', e
```

Comment: thanks this worked for me! If the element is not interactable then you can still send keys using `actions.send_keys(Keys.DOWN).perform()`

Answer (score 0):

Use JS to scroll within a web element. One example of such is given below:

```
def scroll_down_element(self, element):
    try:
        self.browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = 200", element)

    except Exception as e:
        print 'error scrolling down web element', e
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: unfortunately, the above code was resulting into an error... I will post the answer below